# How to debug TWAIN driver

Tags: c#, visual-c++, twain

I am writing a TWAIN virtual data source/Driver in C#. I have implemented as per specs but still it is not loaded as a TWAIN data source.

Following exception is logged:
 We're deliberately skipping this file: C:\Windows\twain_32\DemoDS\DemoDS.ds
[002536553 apps.cpp  649   127 00006C9C]   Condition Code: DS or DSM reported error, application shouldn't display an error

Is it possible to debug driver (.ds) file when DSM try to load it?

I have C++ version working fine but having issues while porting it to c#